# Routing a button to a customized controller method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code that creates a button and routes it to a customized controller method:

```
button_to "Delete", action: "bulk_edit"
```

and the params for action and controller are on par with what I want. However, I keep receiving a UrlGenerationError as it says no route matches. This is my controller method:

```
    def bulk_edit
    @lead = Lead.new 

    print "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
end
```

How am I receiving this error when the method exsists? Cheers~

Comment: yes, of type post under collections but it still cannot find the action

Comment: Did you add that method to your routes file?

Comment: meaning in the following way:

Comment: collection do 
   post 'bulk_edit'
  end

Comment: Check to see if the route looks right: 'rake routes | grep bulk_edit'

Answer (score 0):

If you define "post" method in your routes, you have to use "post" method in your [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) method as well:

```
button_to "Delete", action: "bulk_edit", method: :post
```